# Does the order of the subgroup generated by two elements divide the product of the element orders?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $(G, \cdot)$ be a group, $a,b\in G$ such that $\DeclareMathOperator{\ord}{ord}\ord(a),\ord(b)<\infty$.

Do we then have that $\left|\left<a,b\right>\right|$ divides $\ord(a)\ord(b)$? (Where $\left< a,b \right>$ denotes the subgroup generated by $a$ and $b$)

I managed to show this for the case that $a$ and $b$ commute, however I would be interested if this holds even if they don't.

Comment: The order might be infinite.

Comment: Groups have a wonderful amount of flexibility. You might be interested in [the free product](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_product) of groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$S_3=\langle (12), (23)\rangle$.

Comment: Related: $S_n$ is generated by $(12)$ and $(123\cdots n)$, yet $n!$ rarely divides $2n$.

Comment: And for more fun https://mathoverflow.net/questions/59213/generating-finite-simple-groups-with-2-elements.

Answer (score 4):

The group $$\left\langle\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}\right\rangle$$
has infinite order, in spite of the generators having finite order.